# the notification doesn't show up

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, alarmmanager, alarm

In my app I am using a time picker where the user chooses the time he wants and then when the time comes the app supposed to send the notification to the user. I did everything but the app doesn't send the notification to the user. Please help

P.C. I added the receiver on manifest

It is ok to use java or kotlin..

**Alarm receiver**

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {


override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    val i = Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
    intent!!.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    val pendingActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,0)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!," AdhanNotifacations")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_fajr_icon)
        .setContentTitle("موعد الصلاة حل")
        .setContentText("ان الصلاة كانت على المؤمنين كتابا موقوتا")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(pendingActivity)

    val noifacationManagar = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    noifacationManagar.notify(123,builder.build())
}
}
```

**Setting Activity**
fajrSalah id is a switch button

```
private lateinit var picker : MaterialTimePicker
private lateinit var calender : Calendar
private lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
private lateinit var pendingIntent: PendingIntent

 //صلاة الفجر
    fajrSalah.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            showTimePicker()
        }else{
            //cancelAlarm()
        }
    }
    adhanNotifcationBtn.setOnClickListener {

        setAlarm()

    }

}

private fun showTimePicker(){

    picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
        .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_12H)
        .setHour(12)
        .setMinute(0)
        .setTitleText("حدد الموعد الذي تريدة")
        .build()

    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, "AdhanNotifacations")

    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {

        calender = Calendar.getInstance()
        calender[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = picker.hour
        calender[Calendar.MINUTE] = picker.minute
        calender[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
        calender[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0


    }
}

private fun setAlarm(){
    alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,0)

    alarmManager.setRepeating(

        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calender.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent
    )

    toast("تم تفعيل المنبه")
}

private fun cancelAlarm(){

    alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,0)

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)

    toast("تم الغاء المنبه")

}
private fun createNoificationChannel(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){

        val name : CharSequence = " almuslimChannel"
        val description = "Channel for Alarm Manager"
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel("AdhanNotifacations",name,importance)
        channel.description = description
        val notifcationManager = getSystemService(
            NotificationManager::class.java
        )

        notifcationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I made a space on my channel id that was on my receiver, which causes the receiver to not send the notifications to the users.

now this is the solution to my issue

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {


override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val i = Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
    intent!!.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    val pendingActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,0)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!,"AdhanNotifacations")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_fajr_icon)
        .setContentTitle("موعد الصلاة حل")
        .setContentText("ان الصلاة كانت على المؤمنين كتابا موقوتا")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(pendingActivity)

    val noifacationManagar = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    noifacationManagar.notify(123,builder.build())
}
}
```